# error on Key Value coding when using prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, key-value-coding

I am using the following to create a reference to a view controller in my code like this:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
  if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"detailSegue"]){
    NSIndexPath *indexPath=[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    TRDetailViewController *vc=segue.destinationViewController;
    vc.item=self.items[indexPath.row];
    [vc setValue:self forKeyPath:@"delegate"];
    [vc setValue:indexPath.row forKeyPath:@"itemIndex"];
  }
}
```

and this is declared as in TRDetailViewController

```
@interface TRDetailViewController : UIViewController
  @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *detailLabel;
  @property NSString *item;
  @property (nonatomic, weak)id delegate;
  @property NSInteger itemIndex;
  - (IBAction)deleteItem:(id)sender;
@end
```

but I get the following error

[image]

and I'm not sure why. I am trying to pass the location in an index of the cell selected in a UITableView. If a better way, please let me know. Why am I getting this error?

thx

Comment: thx for edit - had someone talking to me

Comment: Sure! FWIW, i find that I make fewer errors when I prefer objective-c properties to key-value coding. For instance, if you've imported a class and you try to assign a value to a property on that class that is not visible, the compiler lets you know. You don't get that when using the literal string keyPaths that setValue:forKeyPath: takes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setValue:forKey: is expecting an object for its value argument and you are passing it a primitive (in this case, an integer). You can work around this by amending your method to read as follows:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
  if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"detailSegue"]){
    NSIndexPath *indexPath=[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    TRDetailViewController *vc=segue.destinationViewController;
    vc.item=self.items[indexPath.row];
    [vc setValue:self forKeyPath:@"delegate"];
    [vc setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row] forKeyPath:@"itemIndex"];
  }
}
```

And then access it like:

```
[[vc valueForKey:@"itemIndex"] intValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

`setValue:forKeyPath:` requires an object (i.e. `id`) as first argument.

You are instead passing a `NSInteger`.

You will have to use an object type, which means to turn your `itemIndex` into a `NSNumber`.

Then you can store it using

```
[vc setValue:@(indexPath.row) forKeyPath:@"itemIndex"];
```

and retrieve it by

```
NSInteger myIndex = [vc valueForKey:@"itemIndex"].integerValue;
```